# Strip of 0's in Google Earth Engine (SRTM) raster

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to use Google Earth Engine to query for an elevation raster through SRTM. Here is a sample code in Python:

```
# we use the SRTM database
elv = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003')

# Define an EE features polygon based on these bounds
bbox = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-2010000.0, 2260000.0, 5680000.0, 8420000.0], proj = 'EPSG:3395')

# Make pixels with elevation below sea level transparent.
elv_img = elv.updateMask(elv.gt(0))

# Display the thumbnail of styled elevation
url=elv_img.getThumbURL({
    'min': 0, 'max': 10000, 'scale':2.5e3, 'region': bbox,
    'palette': ['006633', 'E5FFCC', '662A00', 'D8D8D8', 'F5F5F5']})
```

[image]

The concern is the strip of "0"s at the top of this raster.

It doesn't relate to the limits of the SRTM data (altering the top extent of the bbox doesn't change the band). Altering the projection doesn't help either. Am I doing something wrong in the code? Is this a problem anyone has encountered before?

Comment: Probably just shuttle orbital mechanics at work -- the northernmost SRTM collection was 60N (between Scotland and the Faroe Islands).

Comment: You ask for `'region': bbox,` but `bbox` extends further north than the limits of the SRTM data .

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fb8cfc3169c0fcb927c0389a89da19f2

Comment: Ah I see, I wondered if that was the problem. In latitudes it's just a bit over the 60 N (60.24). This was helpful, thank you!